# Passing wildcards to routes in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a route using a wildcard, with the syntax I know from L3, but I keep getting a 404.

I registered my route in `routes.php`:

```
Route::get("get_cities/(:num)","QueryController@get_cities");
```

The controller and the function exist and are found when I remove the wildcard. Has the syntax changed?

And while I'm at it: Is there any documentation I can refer to with similar problems, or is it yet to be written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll be wanting something like...

```
Route::get('cities/{id}', 'CityController@showProfile');
```

The documentation has been out for a little while now...

http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters
http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers